# In TypeScript's tsconfig file, how do I exclude 'node_modules' folder but include certain sub files

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

I have a tsconfig like so

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es2015",
    "target": "es2015",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "watch": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "suppressOutputPathCheck": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "dist",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "typings/globals",
    "typings/modules"
  ]
}
```

And I am using webpack to bundle my project files. Most definition files have been added using typings but certain npm modules includes their own definition files. I want to be able to add those to the typescript compilation. Otherwise I get errors like `Cannot find module X`

How do I include those definition files in the compilation?

Comment: I do believe that you are supposed to install the typings anyway:  `typings install npm~packagename --save`

Comment: Thanks. I tried that but I getting a warning `Typings for "mobx-react" already exist in "node_modules\mobx-react\index". You should let TypeScript resolve the packaged typings and uninstall the copy installed by Typings`. And an error `Unable to find "mobx-react" ("npm") in the registry`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> certain npm modules includes their own definition files

These will get picked up (despite the `exclude`) if you set your `module` to `commonjs`

Comment: What should you set it to instead?